# I'm having trouble finding the fluid Viscosity bar in Blender 2.83

Tags: interface, fluid-simulation

I was watching a fluid tutorial, but it was using blender 2.8 while mine is 2.83 and I am having a trouble finding the Viscosity bar. Can you help me solve this problem?

[image: 2.8]

[image: 2.83]

Answer (score 2):

It was renamed as **Diffusion**, enable it (check your 2nd picture)

You can consult official Blender Documentation here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/fluid/type/domain/liquid/diffusion.html